# How to fetch unique values from the given array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, unique

I want to get all the unique values from an array in javascript, while ignoring the casing of the string.

Expected output:

```js
let array = ["pune", "Pune", "PUNE", "पुणे", "400321", "पुणे", "400321"];

// wanted output:
// array == ["pune", "400321", "पुणे"]
console.log(array);
```

What do i need to do to get to this result?

Comment: do you mean only unique values (case insensitive) ?

Comment: In final output do you want to keep the case of value to be same as first occurrence or should be lower cased ?

Comment: I just want one value from three of them as like pune

Comment: @ashwini so given `["pUNe", "PuNe"]` as input, would you want the result to be `["pUNe"]` (first element) or `["PuNe"]` (last element) or `["pune"]` (downcased) or `["PUNE"]` (upcased) as output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert all strings to lowercase and cast the array to a `Set` to remove duplicates. Then convert the set back to an `Array` using the spread syntax.

```js
const arr = ['pune','Pune','PUNE','पुणे',400321,'पुणे',400321];
const uniq = [...new Set(arr.map(x => x.toLowerCase && x.toLowerCase() || x))]

console.log(uniq)
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want all the unique values in an array (ignoring the casing of the values),
you could do so by using an object to group them:

```js
function uniqueValuesCaseInsensitive(values) {
  let unique = values.reduce((acc, val) => {
    let downcased = val.toLowerCase();
    if(!(downcased in acc))
      acc[downcased] = val;
    return acc;
  }, {});
  
  return Object.values(unique);
}

let array=["pune","Pune","PUNE","पुणे","400321","पुणे","400321"];
console.log(uniqueValuesCaseInsensitive(array));
```

As @CodeManiac pointed out you could also use this if you're ok with the output values being downcased:

```js
let array=["pune","Pune","PUNE","पुणे","400321","पुणे","400321"];
console.log([...new Set(array.map(v=> v.toLowerCase()))]);
```

With a library like `lodash` this becomes a bit shorter:

```js
let array=["pune","Pune","PUNE","पुणे","400321","पुणे","400321"];

console.log(_.uniqBy(array, e => e.toString().toLowerCase()));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Alternative is `[...new Set(inp.map(v=> v.toLowerCase()))]`

Comment: @CodeManiac but then you don't preserve the case of the first element (i.e. all will be lowercased). I added it the answer, it's a great solution :) Thanks for pointing this out :)

Comment: Yes definitely, but from given example it seems so i just asked OP for more clarification about this in a [`comment`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57243333/how-to-fetch-unique-values-from-the-given-array-in-javascript#comment100987541_57243333)